# How to calculate current Internet speed in android in every seconds

Tags: android, connection

I want to make an app in android. Which should provide the current internet speed for both wifi and mobile data in every seconds. It is just working like internet speed meter. [image]

so that it should update the connection speed in every second.

How to do it??

Comment: What you want to do is to: 1. get current time. 2. download largeish file from the internet 3. get current time. 4. subtract time3-time1. 5. divide size of 2/time 3

Comment: calculate the current connection speed for every second just like working of internet speed meter. so i want to calculate the download speed and upload speed with every second. Not the Link speed .

Comment: **connection speed** to what?

Comment: Current connection speed. just 0kb for idle and vary with network speed while performing any data access method like browsing downloading...